# Selenium IDE verify either "pattern1" or "pattern2"

Tags: selenium, ide, assert, verify

Hello Selenium IDE Friends,

if have to test by Selenium IDE if a value matches either pattern1 OR pattern2. In PHP i would write:

```
if($value1 == $pattern1 or $value1 == $pattern2)
{
echo "match";
}
```

Does anyone know, how to do this in Selenium IDE like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex pattern:

```
regexp:(${pattern1}|${pattern2})
```

Selenium source:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
    <td>regexp:(${pattern1}|${pattern2})</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```